# Toggle display of table :not first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that starts off showing only the first column:

```
#tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) {
  display:none;
}
```

How can I display all of the other columns when a button is clicked?

Below is what I tried:

```
  $(document).on('click', '#revealbutton', function() {
    $("<style> #tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) { display:show; } <\/style>").appendTo("head");
  });
```

Comment: Its a proposital thing or you missed it ? on your script example you opened a `script` tag and closed a `style` tag it must be `style` in the first tag ?

Comment: Fixed that.  But still does not work with both style tags

Comment: Why are you appending style to the head?  Why not just use `$('#tablegrid tr td').show();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code as `display:table-cell` not `display: show`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#revealbutton', function() {
    $("<style> #tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) { display:table-cell; } <\/style>").appendTo("head");
  });
```

```css
#tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablegrid">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="revealbutton">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you could make something like this

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $("table tr td:not(:first-child)").hide();
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>remove</button>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>adsa</td>
  <td>asdas</td>
  <td>adasd</td>
  <td>adad</td>
  <td>adasd</td>
  <td>asdasd</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that your snippet does the opposite of what the OP is asking.  I think that `.hide()` should be `.show()` and all but the first row should start out hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is appending now!

```
 $('#revealbutton').on('click', function() {
    $("<style> #tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) { display:show; } </style>").appendTo("head");
  });
```

Let me know if that help!

Answer (score 0):

You have correct code,
But it's just the Opening  `script` tag.
replace it with: `<style>/*A code here*/</style>`
Maybe that's just being Confusing?
Besides that, Everything is goood.

```js
  $(document).on('click', '#revealbutton', function() {
    $("<style> #tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) { display:show; } <\/style>").appendTo("head");
  });
```

```css
#tablegrid tr td:not(:first-child) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
<tr id=tablegrid>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This should be the Source code.

Hopes this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I think that you're over complicating things.  Why not just use .show()

```
$(document).on('click', '#revealbutton', function() {
    $('#tablegrid tr td').show();
});
```

It works in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xawdv12y/3/)